# force abnormall signal from child process to parent c

Tags: c, signals, fork

Am using fork so i have a child process and parent. Thing about that the child  waiting a specific integer value from the user lets suppose 5 to terminate normally , in any other case must force the child to terminate abnormally , for example if user inputs the integer value 3. Is there any way to do it with signals? I was thinking about to use WIFEXITED status to catch this signals but i cant make it clear in my mind to make this. Can anyone help me fill a simple code like this :

```
int ans;

if(fork==0){ /*Child process*/
   scanf("%d\n",&ans);
   if(ans==5)exit(1) // terminate normally , that is clear 
   else {
      /*Here is my problem i want to use signal to inform parent that this is an input that i dont want */

   }
  

}else{ /*Parent process */
  /*So here parent with WIFEXITED  status catch this signal and prints out normal or abnormal*/
  if(WIFEXITED(status)) printf("normal"); // ???
  else printf("abnormall"); // ???
}
```

Comment: `WIFEXITED` is not catching signals, it is capturing the termination status *"WIFEXITED(status)
returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main()."* - and you most definitely can use it for your purposes. For more fine-grained control you can use `WEXITSTATUS`

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK how i can force the child terminate abnormally so WIFEXITED  catch that ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you please give an example with a simple code for that ?

Comment: You simply make it terminate, like any other program. With `exit` or with `return` from `main`

Comment: I suggest you to use `WEXITSTATUS` and simply distinguish the different statuses, not "normal/abnormal". BTW, these cannot be used by themselves of course. You need to call `wait/waitpid` to get the status. https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

Comment: What do you mean by exiting "abnormally"? As in a "crash"? An unhandled signal? Calling `abort()`? Something else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude WIFEXITED(status) says that if child terminates normal or abnormall .I want to force the child exit abnormal when it doesnt gets the expective value 5 . How i can do that ?

Comment: Well I *did* give you a couple of examples in my comment... ;) Calling `abort()` is a good way to exit "abnormally". And many signals will cause a process to exit "abnormally" if they aren't handled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  thank you !! Can you please fill my simple program to give me an example ?

Comment: regarding: `if(fork==0){`   do not name the variables the same as a C library function name, especially when that function name is being used else where in the same program.  Such overlapping name usage may be properly handled by the compiler, but us humans can easily be confused by such misuse

Comment: regarding: `if(ans==5)exit(1)`  the exit value `1`  (in general) indicates an error occurred.  Suggest using the macros from `stdlib,h` EXIT_FAILURE  or EXIT_SUCCESS.  example `exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );`  Also, please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `if(WIFEXITED(status)) printf("normal");`  MUCH better to write:  `wait( &status );  if (  WEXITSTATUS(status) ) == 5 )`